Получение длины текста QLabel в пикселях и символах без html тегов
Мне нужно получить длину QLabel в пикселях, QLabel содержит некоторый HTML:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QHBoxLayout


class Win(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = QLabel('<font style = "color:red">а</font>')
        self.l = QHBoxLayout()
        self.l.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.l)
        self.show()
        print(self.label.fontMetrics().boundingRect(self.label.text()).width())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    win = Win()
    app.exec_()

Код возвращает 200 пикселей, что явно больше. 
Как решить эту проблему? По возможности подскажите как можно также получить длину текста в символах без тегов
